# Javascript - Reading binary data when using chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So I am building a Chrome DevTools extension that inspects binary traffic on particular website.

Requests on site are made with `responseType = "blob"`.

Now when I get request with `chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished` and then access its content with `request.getContent()`, I get `string` as response and not `blob`.

This string looks like some kind of binary string but not sure how it is encoded. I tried transforming it to `base64 string` with a lot of different transforms (Utf-8 to latin, Utf-16 to latin, ... ) but nothing gave correct result.

Any idea how to get correct result?

**Update:**

This is comparison of results (as `Uint8Array`) from client and extension.

Client:
`[170, 69, 224, 171, 51, 233, 216, 82, 197, 35, 170, 213, 145, 197, 218, 82, 72, 85, 33, 77, 81, 88, 93, 16, 97, 234, 253, 208, 203, 221, 44, 44]`

Extension:
`[65533, 69, 65533, 65533, 51, 65533, 65533, 82, 65533, 35, 65533, 81, 65533, 65533, 82, 72, 85, 33, 77, 81, 88, 93, 16, 97, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 44, 44]`

Notice how every byte that is over 128 is converted to 65533 byte (Replacement character) in extension?

Now how can I access pure binary data?

Comment: Yes if content is JSON but in my case it's binary content.

Comment: HAR format has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Yes `onRequestFinished` returns object that is HAR entry. But then you request `getContent` on that object. And result is string, that has nothing to do with HAR. It is actual content of response, but in some encoded string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89178/discussion-between-woxxom-and-gapipro).

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = Uint8Array.from(atob(content), c => c.charCodeAt(0)) ;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: @4b0 , hyper link not available <3