# special chars are corrupted while sending the request result to another php page for debug

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

i am trying to create a script that gets the requests in the network tab and sends it to a debug page ,the requests are aes-128-cbc encrypted but they are RAW not base64 so some special chars exist,the problem is that special chars are somehow sent corrupted to the debug page.

for example:
"A test" (without the quotes) is encrypted with 
key test1234 
and iv 1235569767556087 
using the php code

```
openssl_encrypt("A test",'aes-128-cbc',"test1234",OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,"1235569767556087");
```

gave the following result : ��)���,�AM9�,�

which is represented in an integer array as 
[191,242,41,173,235,176,231,44,232,65,77,2,57,170,44,175]

when the encrypted string is sent to the debug page it becomes as following

[239,191,189,239,191,189,41,239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189,44,239,191,189,65,77,2,57,239,191,189,44,239,191,189]

as you can notice each � is represented by 3 bytes (239,191,189) instead of the actual byte

i use google chrome and the js code is as the following:

```
var SendDebugRequest = function(url,posted_data,callback){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "http://127.0.0.1/debug.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status === 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response,xhr.responseURL);
  } else {
    callback(status, xhr.response,xhr.responseURL);
  }
};
xhr.send(posted_data);}
Promise.all(UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes.map( function(node){
var temp = [];
temp[1] = node._request._requestHeaders;
node._request._requestFormDataPromise.then(function(data) { temp[0] =  data;});
node._request.contentData().then(function(data) { temp[2] = data.content;});
return temp;})).then(function(daata){
var posted_data = "encrypted_text=" + encodeURIComponent(daata[0][2]) + "&form_data=" + encodeURIComponent(daata[0][0]) ;
SendDebugRequest('',posted_data,function (status,response,resp_url){});});
```

so any idea about how can i solve the problem?

### thanks in advance

EDIT:
as suggested in the comment , i tried using FormData instead of encodeURIComponent but also gave the same result

i changed

```
var posted_data = "encrypted_text=" + encodeURIComponent(daata[0][2]) + "&form_data=" + encodeURIComponent(daata[0][0]) ;
SendDebugRequest('',posted_data,function (status,response,resp_url){});});
```

to

```
var formData = new FormData();
var encrypted_text = new Blob([daata[0][2]], { type: "application/octet-stream"});
formData.append('encrypted_text', encrypted_text);
formData.append('form_data', daata[0][0]);
SendDebugRequest('',formData,function (status,response,resp_url){});
```

and removed the line

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

EDIT 2 :

The problem is due to chrome giving the text response instead of the actual raw hex response , do you have any idea about how can i achieve this? searching yielded no results , i don't mind using an extension as long as i can send the data to the debug page

Comment: Sounds like a charset mismatch issue. Try enforcing UTF-8 or application/octet-stream explicitly everywhere e.g. via a XHR header or maybe switch to `FormData` API instead of encodeURIComponent.

Comment: i tried using FormData but got the same result

Comment: A raw hash is not text at all, it's binary data (just like a picture or a video). You can't convert it to text by setting any encoding. That's what Base64, hexadecimal dumps and similar encodings address.

Comment: thanks, then how can i access the raw hex response content in google chrome? all i can access is the string

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` cannot handle binary data. You need `multipart/form-data` instead. If it's just a debugging facility, it's probably easier to just serialize in as plain text.

Comment: after removing the xhr.setRequestHeader the contemnt type is sent as multipart/form-data , also by using var_dump($_FILES); in php i can see that the size is 31 instead of 16 , in js , the encrypted_text is a string not the byte array so i tried converting it to utf-8 byte array , i got the 31 byte array again , tried utf-16 i got the 16 byte array but the chars are still corrupted , i guess the question now becomes how to get the actual hex from node._request.contentData() instead of the string

Comment: after doing some search , i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481473/javascript-reading-binary-data-when-using-chrome-devtools-network-onrequestfin which describes my problem , but unfortunately it has no solution